# How to pass Arguments and use those in (resque-status) Resque::JobWithStatus?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

my resque worker class is:

```
require 'resque'
require 'resque/job_with_status'

class PatstatResqueWorker < Resque::JobWithStatus
  @queue = :my_worker_q
  def self.perform(query, label)
    puts "query:"
    puts options['query']
    puts "label:"
    puts options['label']
  end
end
```

and my controller part, where I call this resque is...

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def resque
    job_id = PatstatResqueWorker.create(:query => @query, :label => "yes")
    status = Resque::Plugins::Status::Hash.get(job_id)
  end
end
```

and its not working :(
if i remove the parameter from resque function it says **Wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)** and if i add the parameter section back it says **options not defined** :(
Could you help?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting the "options not defined" error is that you haven't defined `options` in the method that uses it.  Your `self.perform` method expects to receive two distinct arguments, `query` and `label`, but the code inside the method expects to have an `options` hash.  You've got to choose one or the other.

Either do this:

```
def self.perform(query, label)
  # use the parameters we've already defined
  puts "query:"
  puts query
  puts "label:"
  puts label
end

# call it like this
PatstatResqueWorker.create(@query, "yes")
```

Or else do this:

```
# change the method signature to match what you're doing
def self.perform(options)
  puts "query:"
  puts options['query']
  puts "label:"
  puts options['label']
end

# call it like this, with string keys
PatstatResqueWorker.create('query' => @query, 'label' => "yes")
```

Notice that with the hash version, I changed the call to use strings for the hash keys instead of symbols.  You can use symbols if you want, but you'd have to change it in the body of the method as well (i.e. `options[:query]` instead of `options['query']`).  You've just got to be consistent.

Comment: thanks... your solution didn't work 100% but i got the idea of options hash table though. may b resque-status has made some change internally. its sending the job id in the first parameter and other arguments in the 2nd parameter.
so what i m doing now is
`def self.perform(jobid, options)` as resque function.